# Creating column that lists distinct observations

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data frame of observations that looks like this (showing course numbers of college classes offered each term). The columns are very long and of varying lengths

```
  spring   summer   fall
   4a       5b       5c
   4a       9c       11b
   7c       5b       8a 
   ...      ...      ...
```

I want to reformat it to make it look like this. First, I want to create a column, "Course_Names", that shows all names of distinct course offerings possible. Then, I want to count the number of sections of each course offered each semester.

```
   Course_Names   spring   summer   fall
   4a             2        0        0
   5b             0        2        0
   5c             0        0        1
   7c             1        0        0
   8a             1        0        1
   9c             0        1        0
   11b            0        0        1
```

Any advice or links to relevant posts would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by gathering the data and then spreading it again using those functions from tidyr package as follows;

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <-
  data.frame(
    spring = c("4a", "4a", "7c"),
    summer = c("5b", "9c", "5b"),
    fall = c("5c", "11b", "8a")
  )

result <-
  data %>%
  gather(key = "Course_Names", value = "Course") %>%
  group_by(Course_Names, Course) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(key = Course_Names, value = n) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get this solution to work and print out a table in the console! How do I convert the table printed in the console into a data frame?

Comment: You just assign it result <- .... I have edited the post to show how to save it

Comment: `spread` has `fill` argument which will avoid the last `replace`. So you can do `data %>%
  gather(key = "Course_Names", value = "Course") %>%
  count(Course_Names, Course) %>%
  spread(key = Course_Names, value = n, fill = 0) `

Answer (score 6):

In `base R`, an option would be to `stack` the data.frame into a two column dataset and use `table`

```
table(stack(df1))
#    ind
#values spring summer fall
#   11b      0      0    1
#   4a       2      0    0
#   5b       0      2    0
#   5c       0      0    1
#   7c       1      0    0
#   8a       0      0    1
#   9c       0      1    0
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, get the `count` and reshape into 'wide

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    count(name, Course_Names = value) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  Course_Names  fall spring summer
#  <chr>        <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 11b              1      0      0
#2 5c               1      0      0
#3 8a               1      0      0
#4 4a               0      2      0
#5 7c               0      1      0
#6 5b               0      0      2
#7 9c               0      0      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(spring = c("4a", "4a", "7c"), summer = c("5b", 
"9c", "5b"), fall = c("5c", "11b", "8a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get the tidyverse solution to work and print out a table in the console! How do I convert the table printed in the console into a data frame?

Comment: @AnnaJones. You can do `as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(df1)))`. If you are asking about the tidyverse, it is a `tbl_df` which also include `data.frame` class.  you can coerce the output directly to only data.frame class with `as.data.frame`

Comment: I was able to get it into a data frame by using result <- ... and then your solution as @Nareman Darwish suggests above! Thanks!